# Regaring allocating new objects in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm building a "4 in a row" game, Which the user is prompt to choose the number of rows and columns. with that chosen param of the user, im allocating the space by:
'm_PictureBoxsMatrix = new PictureBox[NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns]'
but during the game, the player can change the game properties to a new board size aka new NumberOfRows and new NumberOfColumns.
So after the player changes the board size, I need to reallocate the space.
Am I right ?

The problem is after I'm reallocating the space with
'm_PictureBoxsMatrix = new PictureBox[NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns]' with the new changed parameters. The actual user interface board doesn't change. 
please notice that 'm_PictureBoxsMatrix = new PictureBox[NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns]' is in the UI side and it should be changed accordingly

Comment: This question isn't clear. Can you give us some more background on the game design and also use (not to come off as snooty) paragraphs to break down your points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using multiple controls, you will indeed need to recreate the controls. Creating a new array will help your code, but won't change **at all** the controls in the form's `Controls` collection. The simplest process is either to recreate the form *completely*, else empty out the controls (remembering to `Dispose()` each), and re-create from scratch, adding each `PictureBox` to both the array (`m_PictureBoxsMatrix`) and to the UI `.Controls.Add(...)`).

Comment: @Marc Gravell, how do i recreate the form completely? Can I just dispose all of the controls and then create a new one ? or should I loop in the matrix to remove all controls before allocating new ones ?

Comment: @Alon - if you are keeping the form, then you would need to *for each of the `PictureBox` controls you created*, `.Remove()` it from whichever control collection you originally added it to, and call `Dispose()`. If you are going to just destroy the entire form and recreate it it should happen automatically.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, I have a form, which inside it I have a panel. The panel is the one who contains the matrix of the PictureBox. Can I just remove the panel and recreate the panel ?

Comment: @Alon - pretty much, yes. But make sure you call `Dispose()` on everything you remove.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, for (int i = 0; i < this.panelBoardGame.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                Control ct = panelBoardGame.Controls[i]; 
                panelBoardGame.Controls.Remove(ct);
                ct.Dispose();
            }   like that?

Comment: @Alon - that should do it, yes.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, I have a wierd bug. in my panel.controls.count i have 44 controls but when i reach to the control 22, it gets an arguement out of range exception

Comment: @Alon - oh, right. Yes - I should have spotted that! Either iterate **backwards**, or keep removing from index 0... think about it ;p Once you've removed an item from position 0, the next item is... at position 0.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, should I use iterators or for loop ?

Comment: @Alon - you can't use `foreach` if you are modifying the collection. `for` should be fine; actually the most efficient is `for(int i = collection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {remove at i}` - no copying each time.